# My database context reference is always returning null, how can this be fixed?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have an issue where my database context is null.

I need to call this method in my startup.cs class like this:

```
MorningOrders meds = new MorningOrders();

meds.CompleteOrders();
```

And here is my class:

```
public class MorningOrders
{
    private readonly EbContext _context;

    public MorningOrders()
    { }

    public MorningOrders(EbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public bool CompleteOrders()
    { 
     // process orders
    }
}
```

Everytime I run it though, I get an error saying `_context is null`

Is there a way to fix this?

thanks!

Comment: You're calling the constructor with no parameters, and that doesn't set `_context`. So it's null by default. You have to change to the constructor with a parameter. Why do you need to use the parameterless constructor?

Comment: Or assign it a value in the default constructor.

Comment: Is this asp.net core? If so you need to use the injection framework (or a custom one) and register the DbContext as well as the MorningOrders service.

Comment: @JoeSewell I needed to make that parameterless constructor so I could use it inside my `startup.cs` class.

Comment: @Igor yes, it is a net core Entity Framework web app.  I need to call this one class in `Startup.cs` but can't figure it out because it uses dependency injection.

Comment: I recommend you do a little reading on how DI works and how to configure it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0 That should clear up the problem.

Comment: @Igor I did do a lot of reading on Microsoft, and I made a lot of controllers that use DI and they all work nice. But this is confusing me because I can't figure how how to use DI in a non-controller class and have it be able to be called from `startup.cs`

Comment: @Igor I do have `DbContext` in my `ConfigureServices` section like this: `            services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
                options
                .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));`

Comment: Have you create or generated a class that inherits from `DbContext`? You should remove the default parameterless constructor from `MorningOrders` to begin with.

Comment: @mm8 I did, and I just found a typo in the question I asked which I just edited.  My `dbContext` is actually called `EbContext `...I mistyped when writing it out. But my class `EbContext` inherits from a Microsoft class called, `DbContext`.

Comment: Show your startup.cs file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the parameterless constructor from your class:

```
public MorningOrders()
{ }
```

...and always inject it with a context:

```
using (var context = new EbContext())
{
    MorningOrders meds = new MorningOrders(context);

    meds.CompleteOrders();
}
```

Comment: thanks Ok I removed that empty constructor.  What about the other constructor that has `EbContext` injected into it?  Also, does the `using` statment go inside the `CompleteOrders()` method?  thank you!

Comment: You use the constructor that takes a context the way I showed you in the answer. You need to create the context before you create the `MorningOrders` instance, i.e. in the `Startup` class in this case.

Comment: Oh I see, ok I will keep that constructor.  And I put the `using` statement in my `Startup.cs` file.  This is great, I think I understand this pattern now.  Thanks!